# How to change query string with pretty URL in WordPress using .htaccess file

Tags: php, htaccess

I want to create a SEO friendly URL in WordPress, i am developing a site in WordPress it has several custom pages with custom PHP Script.
I am sending data in id="some text" and matching this text from my database when i GET['id'] the parameter.
i already selected my setting from dashboard.

```
Post name   http://domain.com/sample-post/
```

I have Currently  this URL 
domain.com/parent-page/child-page/?id="some text"

and Now i want this one 
domain.com/parent-page/child-page/some-text
I have modify my .htaccess file here is my code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^parent-page/child-page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ parent-page/child-page/index.php/?id=$1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

i don't know why its not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you failing to supply the trailing slash on the pre-rewrite URL? That regex won't match without it.

Since your /parent-page and /parent-page/child-page are WordPress pages you shouldn't be using .htacceess for this at all, because it would prevent WordPress from loading for those URLs. Instead you should be hooking to `query_vars` so WordPress won't strip your new variable from the querystring and to `rewrite_rules_array` to handle the actual rewrite.

Comment: i am solving this problem since 7 hrs but still facing problem :( whats wrong with this code could you please tell me and fix that issue

Comment: Just to clarify, are these WordPress Pages with some extra logic that you'd like to pass a GET var to, or are they completely unrelated to WordPress but living in the same URL structure?

Comment: parent-page and child-page are originally created from pages section. He is using short code on child-page and php files exist at the plugins directory.

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: how can i fix this problem could you please guide me. i am not expert in wordpress

Comment: are you there...